# Finding Locus of a Midpoint of a Chord

Tags: geometry, locus

Let $A$ and $B$ be points, and let $C$ be a point that varies on the open semicircle with diameter $AB$. Construct squares externally on sides $AC$ and $BC$, and let $D$ and $E$ be the centers of these squares, respectively. Find the locus of the midpoint $M$ of $DE$.

I found that the locus of $M$ is the upper half of the inscribed circle in the semicircle with $AB$ as the diameter, however, I am having trouble proving it, and proving that there are no other places where $M$ can exist. Can I have a hint as to how to prove it geometrically? Thanks!

Comment: i found the locus of $M$ to be circle of diameter half of $AB$ that is tangent to $AB$ and the half circle with diameter $AB$. i used complex numbers to show this.

Comment: You are correct about the locus. Some hints to prove it: Writing $O$ for the midpoint of $\overline{AB}$, show that $\overline{OM}\perp\overline{DE}$. Also, show that $\overline{DE}$ passes through the midpoint of $\stackrel{\frown}{AB}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

Let $O$ the midpoint of $AB$ and $Y$ the point where line $DC$ intercepts the circle$(O, OA)$.

1. Show that $C$ is a point of $DE$.
2. Show that $m(\angle AOY)=90 ^{\circ}$. Use the inscribed angle theorem.
3. Show that $m(\angle DMO)=90 ^{\circ}$.

So, if $Y$ and $O$ are fixed points and $OMY$ is a right-angled triangle, what comes after?

Comment: @ RicardoCruz: Thanks, this is very helpful. I only have one question - How do I prove that this semicircle is the only place where $M$ can exist?

Comment: @Pakquebchsoflwty By the converse of Thales Theorem the circle whose diameter is $OY$ is unique and $M$ is a point of this circle.The "lowest" position where $M$ can be is when $C$ is on $A$ or on $B$.In this case the smaller square becomes a point and the bigger square has its center on $Y$. $M$ will be the midpoint of $DC$ or $EC$ and $M$ will be a point of the perpendicular bisector of $YO$. Therefore $M$ is a point of the upper half semicircle. –  RicardoCruz 1 hour ago

Comment: @ RicardoCruz: Thank you very much :)

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:-**

If we use $A$, $B$ as $(x_i,y_i)$ solution will become a bit complicated so you can try solving it by taking $A$ $(-1,0)$ and $B$ $(1,0)$.

Let the point $C$ be $(\cos x,\sin x)$.

For finding center of the square formed by joining $AC$, we will first have to find their mid point and shift it up by $\dfrac{AC}{2}$ on their $\perp$ bisector. Midpoint of $AC$ is $\left(\dfrac{\cos x-1}{2},\dfrac{\sin x}{2}\right)$, and by using distance form you can easily find the midpoint of the square and then you just have to eliminate $\sin, \cos$ by using the formula $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with trig but isn't the identity $sin^2x + cos^2x = 1$?